# bootstrap poLCA - Rstudio version 3.6.1

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I was trying to run the bootstrap.lca command, however I get the error 'package ‘bootstrap.lca’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)'.
Any ideas on how to run a bootstrap test on my lca?